# Flutter - iOS notifications on closed app not properly receiving

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to receive notifications on app closed on iOS with `firebase_messaging` and `flutter_local_notifications` libraries, if I close the app (leave it to background) the device receives the notification as usual, also stops into the different breakpoints, that's why I know it works, the problem starts when I close the app, as I cannot see breakpoints anymore I can't check if is properly working, any advice?

EDIT: Tested with iPhone 6s with iOS 12.5.5, as Simulator don't receive push notifications.

Libraries version:

`flutter_local_notifications: ^9.4.0`

`firebase_messaging: ^11.2.5`

This is my background message handler on main:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await NotificationService().init();

  print("<PUSH>: Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  print('<PUSH>: Message data: ${message.data}');
  print('<PUSH>: Full message: $message');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    print(
        '<PUSH>: Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
  }

  if (message.data['errorType'] != null) {
    NotificationService().sendLocalNotification(
      EnumToString.fromString(
          NotificationType.values, message.data['errorType']),
      message.data,
    );
  }
}
```

Also, the executable part of the `main.dart`

```
class RealMain {
  static Future<Widget> getApp({bool testing = false}) async {
    await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

    if (!testing) {
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
          _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

      FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

      String? token = await messaging.getToken();
      print('<PUSH>: Token: $token');

      messaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((String token) {
        print('<PUSH>: Token Refresh: $token');
      });

      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        print('<PUSH>: Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
        print('<PUSH>: Message data: ${message.data}');
    

        if (message.notification != null) {
          print(
              '<PUSH>: Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
        }

        if (message.data['errorType'] != null) {
          NotificationService().sendLocalNotification(
            EnumToString.fromString(
                NotificationType.values, message.data['errorType']),
            message.data,
          );
        }
      });
      await NotificationService().init();
    }

    return RestartWidget(
      child: EasyLocalization(
        supportedLocales: GeneralConstants.supportedLocales,
        path: 'lib/app/assets/localizables',
        fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Hey Raph! If you are working on an iOS Simulator then there is one thing you need to know, IOS Simulators does not support local notifications. The IDE itself tells us that the simulator doesn't support notifications so that we need to check those notifications through a real device and it is only possible through Test Flight. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Yes, I know the problem with iOS Simulator and push notifications, I acquired a old iOS device (iPhone 6S, iOS version 12.5.5) to test that

Comment: How did you connect your iPhone while in development mode?

Comment: I used xCode to connect it and ran the Runner package